# continuation of finite additive measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a non-empty set , let $\mathscr{A}$ be an algebra of subsets of$X$ ,and let $\mu$ be a finite additive measure on$\mathscr{A}$ , prove that if $\mu$ is countable additive, in the sense that $\mu (\cup U_n)=\sum \mu(U_n)$ holds whenever $U_n\in\mathscr{A},\cup U_n\in\mathscr{A}$ and$U_n$ are disjointed , then we have a countable additive measure defines on the sigma algebra $\sigma(\mathscr{A})$ which is generated by $\mathscr{A}$ and agrees with$\mu$ on $\mathscr{A}$

---

The hint is consider 
$$\mu^{*}(A)=\inf\{\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\mu(A_k):A_n\in\mathscr{A},n\ge 1,A\in\cup_{k=1}^{+\infty}A_k\}$$We can prove $\mu^{*}$ is an outer measure and agrees with$\mu$ on $\mathscr{A}$ , so a nature way is to restrict $\mu^{*}$ on $\sigma(\mathscr{A})$but I have trouble prove the countably additive property, I figure out since it's a restrict of an outer measure so we have the countably subadditive property, but how to prove the other sides of the inequality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a proof of [Carathéodory's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory's_extension_theorem) on extensions of pre-measures on a ring to a measure on the corresponding $\sigma$-algebra. I suggest you look up any good measure theory textbook which includes the proof of this statement. Personally I have learned measure theory in French and even though my textbook did include the proof, I am not sure it is going to help you. I assume your course might include some references, so I encourage you to look them up. This is a very famous theorem, so a proof of it is very easy to find.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Sorry , you are right

Comment: Don't apologize, your question is a legitimate one, it just so turns out it has a well-known answer!